# Remove noise from Load Cell ADC Reading

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing

I have connected my load cell to raspberry pi. I have used ADS1231 from TI and python code on my raspberry pi to get adc readings at 80 samples/sec or 80Hz sampling speed. As you know the adc signals do contain some spikes or noise which i want to remove and get the stable reading. I have read many articles redaring Fourier transform and various other articles on removing noise from the signal.

Can any body guide me on using any dsp method in python for my application ? I don't know much about DSP and how to implement them. Any library in python or any example code can be of help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have much DSP experience either, but I think what you are looking for is `scipy.signal`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/signal.html

Comment: I have read about IIR, FIR and various filters but have no idea on how to implement in my application....